# Change <p> and <h> element when selecting something from dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, chart.js

I have 2 dropdowns. One for the region and one for the category. When I have both selected it shows me a div where a graph is located which I created with chart.js. Below the Graph there is a  element for the category and `<p>` element for the number.

For example : I choose Munich and Einnahmen (Profits) it will show me the Munich graph and below I want it to list "Einnahmen" and the number (which I will get from a database later on). But how do I change these 2 dynamically?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.boxy').hide();
  $("#selectField1, #selectField2").on("change", function() {
    $('.boxy').hide();
    $('#' + $('#selectField1').val() + $('#selectField2').val()).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectField1" class="form-control-sm">
  <option value='hannover'>Hannover</option>
  <option value='munich'>München</option>
</select>
<select id="selectField2" class="form-group form-control-sm">
  <option value='einnahmen'>Einnahmen</option>
  <option value='registrierungen'>Registrierungen</option>
  <option value='kunden'>Kunden</option>
</select>



<div class="card-body ">
  <div id="gesamteinnahmen" class="boxy"><canvas id="gesamtChart"></canvas> </div>
  <div id="hannovereinnahmen" class="boxy"><canvas id="hannoverChart"></canvas></div>
</div>
<div class=" card-footer d-flex flex-wrap bg-c-blue order-card p-0">
  <div class="col-12 px-0">
    <div class="text-center p-4">
      <h4>342</h4> // --------------------- SHOULD CHANGE 1
      <p class="mt-2">Kunden</p> // --------SHOULD CHANGE 2
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: in your change handler, add `console.log('#' + $('#selectField1').val() + $('#selectField2').val());` ... now, can you see any elements that would be selected using that selector? ... how is that even trying to target the `h4` and `p` elements? they don't have an `id`, yet your selector is `#municheinnahmen` or `#munichregistrierungen` etc

Comment: this is the code to select the graph. I am asking for an approach to combine it with also selecting an h4 and p element simultaneously.

Comment: ebrowkin: I've converted your code into a (theoretically) runnable Snippet, in order that we can reproduce your described problem with your code. Can you link to the appropriate plug-in that you're using in order to have it reproduce your situation more accurately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code should work for you

```js
var menu1 = document.getElementById('selectField1');
var menu2 = document.getElementById('selectField2');
var value1= document.getElementById('value1');
var value2= document.getElementById('value2');

menu1.setAttribute("onchange","setValue1()");
menu2.setAttribute("onchange","setValue2()");

function setValue1() {
    value1.innerHTML = menu1.value;
}
function setValue2() {
    value2.innerHTML = menu2.value;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML CODE -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="selectField1" class="form-control-sm">
      <option value='hannover'>Hannover</option>
      <option value='munich'>München</option>
    </select>
    <select id="selectField2" class="form-group form-control-sm">
      <option value='einnahmen'>Einnahmen</option>
      <option value='registrierungen'>Registrierungen</option>
      <option value='kunden'>Kunden</option>
    </select>
    <div class="card-body ">
      <div id="gesamteinnahmen" class="boxy"><canvas id="gesamtChart"></canvas> </div>
      <div id="hannovereinnahmen" class="boxy"><canvas id="hannoverChart"></canvas></div>
    </div>
    <div class=" card-footer d-flex flex-wrap bg-c-blue order-card p-0">
      <div class="col-12 px-0">
        <div class="text-center p-4">
          <h4 id="value1">342</h4> // --------------------- SHOULD CHANGE 1
          <p class="mt-2" id="value2">Kunden</p> // --------SHOULD CHANGE 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here I have updated your java script code and html code a little bit    by adding id to `<h4>` and `<p>` tags as well as set attributes `onchange` to `select`.